# Time complexity of this unique permutations algorithm

Tags: algorithm, permutation

What is the time complexity on the following [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-permutations-string-set-2/)?

I am aware that permutations without checking duplicates take `O(n!)`, but I am specifically interested in the `shoudSwap` function, which is shown below:

```
// Returns true if str[curr] does not match with any of the 
// characters after str[start] 
bool shouldSwap(char str[], int start, int curr) 
{ 
    for (int i = start; i < curr; i++)  
        if (str[i] == str[curr]) 
            return 0; 
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: complexity is O(curr-start), not O(n). I don't see any n here

Comment: @mangusta pls look at the url link included in the post which has all details. Basically shoudSwap called with input range 0 to n.

Comment: Important information should not be behind a link, but included in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 1):

If n is the size of the char array `str[]`, then the time complexity of shouldSwap() is `O(n)` because it will iterate at most once over every element in the `str` array.

Comment: so the whole complexity is O(n * n!) ?

Comment: And `n * n!` is approximately `(n + 1)!`

Comment: @JimMischel Yep. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @AbsoluteSpace.